# "The command SET SOLUTIONDIR exited with code 3" in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio

I'm getting the following error when trying to build Hexchat in VisualStudio 2015. Some of those paths are wrong, so I would like to change them.

How do I change those path in Visual Studio 2015?

```
Error   MSB3073 The command "
SET SOLUTIONDIR=C:\Users\olivi\Desktop\Hexchat\win32\..\
powershell -File "C:\Users\olivi\Desktop\Hexchat\win32\..\win32\version-template.ps1" "C:\Users\olivi\Desktop\Hexchat\win32\..\win32\installer\hexchat.iss.tt" "C:\Users\olivi\Desktop\Hexchat\win32\..\..\hexchat-build\Win32\bin\hexchat.iss"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\..\Inno Setup 5\iscc.exe" /dPROJECTDIR="C:\Users\olivi\Desktop\Hexchat\win32\installer\" /dAPPARCH="Win32" "C:\Users\olivi\Desktop\Hexchat\win32\..\..\hexchat-build\Win32\bin\hexchat.iss"

:VCEnd" exited with code 3. installer
```

I got this in the output window:

```
The specified path cannot be found
22>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(123,5): error MSB3073: The command "
22>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(123,5): error MSB3073: SET SOLUTIONDIR=C:\Users\olivi\Desktop\Hexchat\win32\..\
22>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(123,5): error MSB3073: powershell -File "C:\Users\olivi\Desktop\Hexchat\win32\..\win32\version-template.ps1" "C:\Users\olivi\Desktop\Hexchat\win32\..\win32\installer\hexchat.iss.tt" "C:\Users\olivi\Desktop\Hexchat\win32\..\..\hexchat-build\Win32\bin\hexchat.iss"
22>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(123,5): error MSB3073: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\..\Inno Setup 5\iscc.exe" /dPROJECTDIR="C:\Users\olivi\Desktop\Hexchat\win32\installer\" /dAPPARCH="Win32" "C:\Users\olivi\Desktop\Hexchat\win32\..\..\hexchat-build\Win32\bin\hexchat.iss"
22>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(123,5): error MSB3073:
```

It's resulting from the following command:

```
    <Exec Command="%(PreBuildEvent.Command)$(_BuildSuffix)" Condition="'%(PreBuildEvent.Command)' != ''"/>
```

Comment: The error message is clumsy.  It shows the *complete* set of commands that you used in your build event.  It does not tell you which *specific* command failed with error 3.  It was not SET.  Look in the Output window for a more specific error message.  And if necessary edit the build event to try them one at a time until your find the troublemaker.  Fwiw, error 3 usually means "invalid path".  All those `..` don't help with that.

Comment: Ok, I'll look that up.